# I have a trouble about using "$rootScope.$broadcast" and "$on"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a trobule about using $rootScope.$broadcast and $scope.$on

I have a one module and two controller(Controller1 & Controller2).

```
    var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("Controller1",function ($scope,$rootScope){
$scope.$on("msgUpdated",function (event,data){
console.log(data.message);
})
app.controller("Controller2",function ($scope,$rootScope){
$scope.msg = "Hi!";
$rootScope.$broadcast("msgUpdated",{message:msg});
});
```

This above is my code.

The problem is that my Controller1's $scope.$on is not working.
Why? I don't get it.
and, How can I fix it to fire Controller1's $scope.$on ?

Comment: How and where are you binding those controllers to HTML?

Comment: I have two directive.

Comment: And they both share the same `$rootScope` at the same time?

Comment: directive 1's object is return { templateUrl:"index1.html" controller:"Controller1" } and directive 2's object is return { templateUrl:"index2.html" controller:"Controller2"}.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/8a77t445/ But I see two big issues in your code (you should have seen both if you opened the developer console): (1) You are not closing `})` of the first controller and second `msg` is undefined in the second controller, it should be `{message: $scope.msg}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
        <h1>{{msg1}}</h1>
        <input ng-model="test" ng-blur="sendMsg()"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Controller2">
        <h1>{{msg2}}</h1>
        <input ng-model="test" ng-blur="sendMsg()"/>
    </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Controller1',['$rootScope','$scope',function($rootScope,$scope){
    $scope.msg1 = "Start";
    $scope.sendMsg = function() {
        $rootScope.$emit('msg',$scope.test);
    };
    var cleanup = $rootScope.$on('msg2', function (event,data) {
        $scope.msg1 = data;
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', cleanup);
}])
.controller('Controller2',['$rootScope','$scope',function($rootScope,$scope){
    $scope.msg2 = "Start2";
        $scope.sendMsg = function() {
        $rootScope.$emit('msg2',$scope.test);
    };
    var cleanup = $rootScope.$on('msg', function (event,data) {
        $scope.msg2 = data;
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', cleanup);
}]);
```

Here is fiddler:
I always use $rootScope.$emit and clean up.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbqsbLyg/